# Comment xml files in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse

Trying comment XML lines in `Eclipse Mars`. `CTRL+\` or `CTRL+SHIFT+\` not working. How to solve this problem?

Comment: `XML` files don't have `\\\` or `\\*` comments. They have it in the format `<!--`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can you try `ctrl+shift+c` in order to comment.

Works on Version: Mars Release (4.5.0), tested

Also the Eclipse documentation explicitly says it works for the XML editor.

Reference: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.xmleditor.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Frxmltoolskey.html

Comment: Works on Mars Milestone 5 (4.5.0M5) for me. Make sure you use the xml-editor, not the text-editor.

Comment: Ok it works with XML editor. I was opened XML file it with ant editor. Anyway then it is strange that I can't comment in ANT editor